# Do I need a post workout meal if I eat right before my workout?

Tags: eating-habits, post-workout

So we all know about pre and post workout meals and how important they are. Due to my current scheduling at college especially since it is my last year I always find myself doing my workouts directly after I eat dinner. I had a while ago asked my doctor if this was a bad thing and according to him if I am eating directly before my body will simply be delaying digestion to after my workout and my body is able to return to its normal states. He is not the only one to mention this and from what I have gathered it is no myth. Depending on how long you wait before engaging in strenuous activity your body may delay digestion and due to how soon I do afterwords (less than 5 min) I certainly am.

Now when it comes to post workout meals many are arguing half one way half another some say I should still digest something after I workout others say there is no need. In my OPINION which is not at all to knowledgeable about this People saying I absolutely should eat something after makes no sense to me. If I am eating directly before hand and my digestion is being delayed there should be a small in fact a very minimal difference between that and choosing to eat my meal after.

So who is right in this situation? And if I should be eating something after what is pointing to that, why should I be?

Comment: It is possible. Research is mixed on post workout meals for weightlifting/strength, but def indicated for prolonged endurance exercise. What had of workouts are you doing?

Comment: @JohnP I have been doing weightlifting routines every once in a while I will do some conditioning or endurance nut many lifting. I know research is a bit mixed however I almost think in this situation the argument arises that the delayed digestion isn't somehow replenishing my body in any way and due to this being my last meal of the day it will be approximately another 12 hours before I intake something again. My lifting workouts take place usually from a 45 min to 1 hour period. My endurance and aerobic conditioning workouts take about the same time.

Comment: Based off majority studies, you should try to consume some form of protein after a workout to replenish glycogen and refill your body with protein of course people have their own styles and what works for them may well not work for you

Comment: @Twyxz but as my question states above how is eating a meal and having my digestion halted and then resumed after the physical activity any different than consuming the same thing after. Lets assume that the meal I am eating contains everything necessary to replenish the body and even more would I still need to consume something after the workout?

Comment: @DigitalOddity I would say yes. This is my opinion hence it's not in an answer but you would be using a lot of the energy during your workout, the digestion continuing will not be the full amount of food you consumed. Therefore even having just a small meal after a workout would still be beneficial to you.